# Duplicate a folder (size 150MB - 200MB) of one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket of different region Using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to copy a folder (size 150MB - 200MB) of one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket of the different region using PHP or in S3 term "**duplicate all objects with the prefix of an S3 bucket into objects with a different prefix to another S3 bucket**"

I have tried below code but it's not workings

```
$s3 = new S3Client(['credentials' => $credentials, 'version' => 'latest','region' => $region,'debug' => false ]); 
$s3->registerStreamWrapper(); 
$result = $s3->uploadDirectory("s3://{$source_bucket}/{$key}",$target_‌​bucket);
```

and I have also tried to list out all objects (using listObject function) from source bucket then copy it (Using copyObject function ) into destination bucket. But this process is consuming too much time.

Any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to do an automated copy, you should use the S3 console.

Someone had your problem before:
[How can I copy clone/duplicate a folder on S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3409706/how-can-i-copy-clone-duplicate-a-folder-on-s3)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but No, I have to do it with my PHP code only. no third party software and all.

Answer (score 0):

You really, really should use something like the `aws s3 sync` command in the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

If you write it yourself, you will need to recurse through all the files and issue an individual `copy` command for each object, plus error handling. There is no "copy all files in this path" command in Amazon S3.